# Adding jquery effect to dropdown menu and aligning dropdown menu exactly below Hover tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to move the dropdown box to align exactly under the news tab.?
Currently the dropdown under the news was exactly not under the news tab(moved right).
And adding a jquery effect to the drop down menu

http://jsfiddle.net/A7rvZ/7/

Comment: As a tip, the more you work on your questions the better answers you'll get. That means posting relevant part of your code here as well as the example, and properly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code with your fiddle. Modify the below code with what ever kind of animation you want. Take reference from [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
 $('#coolMenu .pink p a').mouseover(function() {
        $('#coolMenu .pink ul').animate({
            height: ['toggle'],
            opacity: 0.75
        }, 3000, function() {
            $('#coolMenu .pink ul').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });​
```

For aligning the ul on hover, use some css like "margin-left" for selector `#coolMenu ul` .